# Problem with selecting correct package in cmake

Tags: cmake

I have troubles to select to correct package within my CMakeLists.txt. I want to cross compile a project for a different platform and have the cross compiler toolchain installed. My CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH is set to /home/raspberrypi4/qt5.15.
However, if I try to find the package:

```
find_package(QT NAMES Qt5 COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)
find_package(Qt${QT_VERSION_MAJOR} COMPONENTS Widgets REQUIRED)
```

I get the wrong qt folder:

```
Checking file [/home/raspberrypi4/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake]
Checking file [/home/raspberrypi4/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake]
Checking file [/home/raspberrypi4/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/cmake/Qt5Widgets/Qt5WidgetsConfig.cmake]
Checking file [/home/raspberrypi4/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/cmake/Qt5Gui/Qt5GuiConfig.cmake]
Checking file [/home/raspberrypi4/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/cmake/Qt5Core/Qt5CoreConfig.cmake]
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

Even with specifying the folder in the CMakeLists.txt

```
find_package(Qt5 5.15 REQUIRED PATH /home/raspberrypi4/qt5.15/)
```

it still doesn't work:

```
Checking file [/home/raspberrypi4/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake]
Checking file [/home/raspberrypi4/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake]
Checking prefix [/home/raspberrypi4/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/cmake/]
Checking file [/home/raspberrypi4/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/cmake/Qt5PATHConfig.cmake]
Checking file [/home/raspberrypi4/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/cmake/qt5path-config.cmake]
Checking prefix [/home/raspberrypi4/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/cmake/]
Checking file [/home/raspberrypi4/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/cmake/Qt5PATHConfig.cmake]
Checking file [/home/raspberrypi4/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/cmake/qt5path-config.cmake]
CMake Error at /home/raspberrypi4/sysroot/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/cmake/Qt5/Qt5Config.cmake:28 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Qt5PATH" with any
  of the following names:

    Qt5PATHConfig.cmake
    qt5path-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Qt5PATH" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Qt5PATH_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "Qt5PATH" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:21 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Could you give me a hint how to solve this?

Comment: Also found a post  with the hint to set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH pointing to the .pc pointing to the pc files of the lib, but this also doesn't work (no change to the parts above)

Comment: Looking into the search path `/home/raspberrypi4/sysroot/usr/lib/...`, it seems that your **toolchain** assigns `/home/raspberrypi4/sysroot` to the [CMAKE_SYSROOT](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_SYSROOT.html) and sets variable [CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PACKAGE.html) to ONLY. That is, only directories under sysroot are searched, and prefixes (like `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`) are treated **relative to sysroot**.